# Is there a way to intercept every system call an application makes in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I want to write an app (in C, executable and start it from command line) that is basically monitoring what system calls are being made in the user space. You can think of it as a filter. If the process that made the call is of interest, store the fact that a sys call is being made, otherwise do nothing. If they are made by some specific process it needs to store which process and what sys call made. Is there any way to achieve this? Is this achievable from user space or I should write some kind of driver?

EDIT 1:

The app will not use any GUI. I want it to be launched (as an executable) through a command line and wait the stop signal in that cmd. Also, receive the PID of the process to be monitored or "all" if it should monitor all processes in user space. I want it to collect data about apps in terms of what sys calls they are making, what arguments and store that info for processing it with other app which is not the object of this question.

EDIT 2:

No, I can't recompile monitored apps. For example I want to monitor Spotify, Chrome or whatever others. Maybe I made a mistake calling them apps, I want to monitor processes that are running in user space.

Comment: Are you familiar with `strace` ?

Comment: [`strace` manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html)

Comment: ***Why do you ask?*** and what will happen to you if your instrumentation is not perfect?

Comment: **Please improve your question by motivating it and give more details**. Is the monitored application statically linked? Can it be any executable? Is it open source? Does it use some GUI toolkit (e.g. [GTK](https://gtk.org/)...) ? Is it a daemon running for months? Is it a small executable of a few hundred kilobytes, or a monster application like Firefox? Does it generate machine code (like [SBCL](https://sbcl.org/) does)? Does it accept plugins with [dlopen(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you want to understand and use [ptrace(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html) (and perhaps [chroot(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chroot.2.html), the details of [execve(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) and [elf(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html), or [ld.so(8)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html)...)

The [strace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) utility is open source, and uses `ptrace`. And so does the [GNU gdb](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger.

You may want to study their source code.

Be aware and scared of potential [heisenbugs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug).

The [GNU glibc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) is open source (and contains the dynamic linker `ld.so`). With efforts, you could consider patching it and using Ian Taylor's [libbacktrace](https://github.com/ianlancetaylor/libbacktrace) inside it.

If you are allowed to recompile the observed application from its source code in C or C++ compiled by a recent [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/), consider perhaps developing your [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) (maybe starting from [Bismon](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/) in end of 2021).

> Is this achievable from user space ?

### *Yes*, but do budget several *months* of efforts.

Remember that a clever user could recompile his/her own version of the Linux kernel (perhaps with an improved [GNU libc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/)) and avoid your instrumenting layer.

PS. My intuition is that your ill defined problem could be related to [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem) or to the [Halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem). I recommend starting a PhD thesis on your topic.